# best practice for axis2 client projects in wso2

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-integration-studio

I have a WSO2 Axis2 Service project, that has a dependency on five other web services.  I have generated the service with WSO2 developer studio 2.1, so the service is a maven project.

If I use the developer studio wizard for creating the axis2 client projects, the wizard creates the clients as eclipse projects, and not a maven projects.

I am thinking that it would be cleaner for me to create each client project from scratch as maven projects (using the wsdl2code plugin) rather than use the developer studio wizard.  These five maven client projects can then be added as dependencies to the service project.

What is the best practise for managing the relationship between service and client code in WSO2 projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the use case. Developer Studio is really helpful for someone with limited knowledge to start with and also with its wizards you do not miss the steps that are essential in completing end scenario. But in your particular use case where you need to generate lots service stubs it will be easy to use Maven and automate client stub generation. In WSo2 we generate lots of service stubs and use Maven to automate [that.](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/service-stubs/) .If you need more governance on that you can use some repository to manage WSDLs and then use maven plugin to pick wsdls from there. So whenever you change your service your client stubs will reflect those changes.